# Input value contains specific characters anywhere

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a directive that validates an input field to make sure it doesn't contain `&`, `<`, `>`

```
.directive('refValidate', [function () {

var regExp = /^[&\<\> ]*$/;

return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

        function myValidation(value) {
            if (!regExp.test(value)) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('validRef', true);
            } else {
                ctrl.$setValidity('validRef', false);
            }
            return value;
        }
        ctrl.$parsers.push(myValidation);
    }        
};

}]);
```

It only sends back false if the value begins with the specified characters, where  need to check if the value contains them anywhere in the value.

**Question**

How do I amend my reg exp to check for the specified characters anywhere in the input value?

Comment: `/^[&\<\> ]*$/` => `/[&<>]/`

Comment: Well that was simple :o add it as answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match any single occurrence of `<`, `>` or `&` anywhere in the string, but your regex matches a string that contains 0 or more `<`, `>`, `&` or spaces only. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XYqcwY/1) and its [visual graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B%26%5C%3C%5C%3E%20%5D*%24):

[image]

You need to use

```
var regExp = /[&<>]/;
```

Also, the chars you have in the character set are not any special, no need to escape them.